# Enable / Disable Windows Mouse Hover Windows Activation Programmatically

Tags: windows, winapi, autohotkey

How can I enable or disable the "active window on mouse hover" (found in Control Panel / Ease of Access) programatically?

Comment: Try to find with [regmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896652.aspx) if changing it through gui changes any registry key value. If yes, use AutoHotkey registry manipulation commands to set necessary value of that registry key.

Comment: I would suggest that that is a user configuration option, and you should not normally be changing it without the users express permission... in which case, they probably would go and make the change themselves.

Comment: @vasili111: I have no idea if the same is true for Mouse Hover Activation, but I would point you to [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/01/23/10491935.aspx) which gives a hint as to why your suggested approach may have no effect. The last line also serves to back up my other comment.

Comment: maybe I better explain better... it's for me) I'm the ultimate user) I just wanted to write some kind of script that i can assign to a hotkey so that I can toggle it. Why? Because it is damn annoying... this hover thing.. except when I need it. Then it is incredibly useful for my work (and not so annoying, because when I'm using it in that work situation I don't seem to trigger too often windows accidentally)

Comment: so my understanding is that I can change some registry key and then it is ok until the next login? that's fine

Comment: If registry does not help than if there can be used any API call (as in your link) then you can do it with [DLLCall](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/DllCall.htm). Also you can do it by GUI automation.

Comment: @vasili111 Changing values inside the registry is common and everybody does it ...  but it is dangerous considering different versions of Windows. I found that some thing are quite stable inside the registry while others are frequently changed by Microsoft.